# I need to convert a string to a list in python 3, how would I do this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a text file with a list saved in it, I know I could use some other object serialization for this, but I am just trying to do this with a text file cause why not.  So I have a string variable, that has a list in it, but how do I turn the string back into a normal list.  Here is my code

```
    #the normal list
    list1 = [1,2,3]

    #changing the list to a string so that it can be written to a text file
    str_list = str(list1)
```

So now what code do I need to change the list from a string to a normal list.

Answer (score 3):

You may use `ast` module with [literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) function:

```
import ast
l = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

Or [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module (warning! it works only for some subset of string representations, e.g. list of numbers - example given by you):

```
import json
l = json.loads(s)
```

Comment: `s = "['Uh', 'oh']"`

Comment: Yes, string representation isn't always valid json syntax. Although it's valid for OP testcase. I'm gonna clarify the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ast.literal_eval`:

```
>>> s="[1,2,3]"
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval(s)
[1, 2, 3]
```